# How do I pass the contents of a textbox into angular js as an input parameter, rather than a $scope variable?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jsp

Currently, I know how to collect the input from a textbox and use it in a `$scope` variable.  But what if I don't want to use a `$scope` variable?  What if I simply want to pass the input in as a parameter to a function?

CURRENTLY:

I have some JSP that looks like this:

```html
<textarea
  required="true"
  spellcheck="on"
  data-ng-model="editTools.productDescription"
  rows="4"
>
</textarea>
```

I also have a button in JSP that calls a function in Angular JS:

```html
<button 
  id="description-submit-button"
  data-ng-click="mySpecialFunction()"
  buttonType="${'primary'}"
  htmlButtonType="${'button'}"
>
  <text>"Submit"</text>
</button>
```

So, I understand that this works.  I am assigning a value to `$scope.editTools.productDescription` and then `mySpecialFunction()` uses that value.

But how would I accomplish the same thing without using a `$scope` variable?  I'd like to be able to say something like `data-ng-click="mySpecialFunction({the stuff the user typed in the text box})"`

Is this possible?  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to declare your model variable in the controller.  You can change your `textarea` to this so that the model is `myVariable` (you can name it whatever you want):

```html
<textarea
    required="true"
    spellcheck="on"
    data-ng-model="myVariable"
    rows="4">
</textarea>
```

Then you can pass `myVariable` directly into the `mySpecialFunction` call in the HTML like this:

```html
<button 
  id="description-submit-button"
  data-ng-click="mySpecialFunction(myVariable)"
  buttonType="${'primary'}"
  htmlButtonType="${'button'}"
>
  <text>"Submit"</text>
</button>
```

Now in your controller your function would look something like this:

```js
$scope.mySpecialFunction = function (value) {
    // value === myVariable
    // do something with it here
};
```

But just to note, that angularjs does in fact add `myVariable` to the `$scope` behind the scenes, so if you really wanted to you could still access the value with `$scope.myVariable` in your controller.

Comment: Thanks, that addresses everything I was wondering about!

Comment: Also: it sounds like there is no way to pass a variable into a function as a parameter *without* also adding it to `$scope` behind the scenes?